# Ignore curl response body in c++

Tags: c++, http, curl

I am doing a post request using CURL in c++ and I wanted to know if theres a way to ignore the response body that gets printed to the output. This is what my code looks like currently

```
  if (curl) {
    // Set url
    curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_URL, str_url);

    // Set header
    list = curl_slist_append(list, header);
    curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, list);

    // Set request type and data
    curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_POST, 1);
    curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, body);
    curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDSIZE, (long)strlen(body));
    res = curl_easy_perform(curl);
```

everything works but I keep getting the response body posted to the output and I just want to ignore it since all I need is the response code. With the command line I can make a curl request with the following `curl --silent --output` to ignore it but is there a way to do this in c++?

Comment: If you check the documentation there are many ways to call easy_perform and/or set options. If none of them work for you, you’ll have to use the more complicated api. The curl_easy functions are nice but I don’t believe they cover 100% of curl functionality.

Comment: Easy enough to add your own data handler and not print anything in it.

Comment: Set a write callback with `CURLOPT_WRITEFUNCTION`. The default callback is `fwrite(stdout, ...)`; that's what produces the output.

Comment: @IgorTandetnik Thanks! That seemed to do the trick!